# MVC Data Annotations corresponding DateTime picker not showing in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a model like this

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

and this property of datetime should render a DateTime picker in all the browsers , but it is not happening in Firefox (ver. 38.0.5 ) it is working in Google Chrome , **is there any solution for it ?**

```
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }**
```

View code

```
@model MVCMovie.Models.Movie
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()   
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            // @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
    </div>
    ....
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* ... */
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome and Edge - [refer browser comparison](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-44/firefox-40/ie-11/ie-Edge%2013.html). Use a jquery plugin.

Comment: @Stephen , any specific plugin that you recommend for free, and how you would change the view code ? kindly help for the code improvement

Comment: No recommendations, but [jQuery ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are both popular choices. But there are many others.

Comment: @Stephen , you showed my the correct path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my model like this

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

         [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

         [Required]  
        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

       .....
    }
```

added jQueryUI  NuGet Package

created a bundle like this

```
//Create bundel for jQueryUI  
            //js  
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/jqueryui.js"));
            //css  
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssjqryUi").Include(
                   "~/Content/jqueryui.css"));
```

and in the view added this sections in the bottom

```
@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-60:+0"
        });

    });
</script>
}
```

it is now working

[image]